# getting ConnectTransportException while fetching TransportClient instance in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using TransportClient to create elasticsearch client instance with below code.

```
public static Client getInstance() {
    String ipAddress = MessageTranslator.getMessage("es.cluster.ip");
    int transportClientPort = Integer.parseInt(MessageTranslator
                .getMessage("es.transportclient.port"));

    logger.debug("got the client ip as :" + ipAddress + " and port :"
            + transportClientPort);
    if (instance == null) {
        logger.debug("the client instance is null, creating a new instance");
        ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = ImmutableSettings
                .settingsBuilder();
        settings.put("node.client", true);
        settings.put("node.data", false);
        settings.put("node.name", "node-client");
        settings.put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch");
        settings.build();
        instance = new TransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        ipAddress, transportClientPort));
        logger.debug("returning the new created client instance...");
        return instance;
    }
    logger.debug("returning the existing transport client object connection.");
    return instance;
}
```

The issue is some times the code is working and indexing data, but some times I'm getting the below issue.

> 14-08-2014 12:49:07,846 DEBUG
>   [elasticsearch[node-client][transport_client_worker][T#8]{New I/O
>   worker #8}] org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.Log4jESLogger 104 -
>   [node-client] disconnected from [[Nuke - Frank
>   Simpson][P_OU-PZbTXyimWCOvkC7ow][aricloudvmserver3.aricent.com][inet[/10.203.238.139:9300]]],
>   channel closed event 14-08-2014 12:49:11,134 DEBUG
>   [elasticsearch[node-client][generic][T#1]]
>   org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.Log4jESLogger 109 -
>   [node-client] failed to connect to node
>   [[#transport#-1][BGHWV2099][inet[/10.203.238.139:9300]]], removed from
>   nodes list org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException:
>   [][inet[/10.203.238.139:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:683)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:643)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:610)

Please help me to find the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You are using a TransportClient, which doesn't instantiate a Node. You could remove the node-related settings (node.client, node.data, node.name). The only setting you need is the cluster name. Have you tried removing these?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me. If this is an intermittent issue, it can be attributed to:

- Lost connectivity

Also as suggested in the previous post, remove the node related settings and try setting below mentioned properties

```
settingsBuilder.put("cluster.name", searchClusterName);
settingsBuilder.put("client.transport.sniff", true);
settingsBuilder.put("http.enabled", "false");
```

Try this out and share your findings